# Eloqua - How to obtain 'Form Submit' activity information, including Campaign name, using BULK API

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I would like to obtain 'Form Submit' activity information using the BULK API.

This link provides a list of activity fields I can specify as a part of the export definition. It includes the 'CampaignId'. I would additionally like to obtain the Campaign name associated with this CampaignId. 
Is there a way to achieve this via the same BULK API export definition or do I have to make additional BULK API/REST API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make an additional REST API call to retrieve the Campaign Name using the [GET /assets/campaign/{id}](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/#Developers/RESTAPI/2.0%20Endpoints/Campaigns/get-assets-campaign.htm) endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a side question - What is the staged data order on? The fact that I can page on the '/contacts/exports/{id}/data' endpoint implies that the data is sorted but on which field and is this configurable?

Comment: At this time the data is not ordered, and there is not an ability to order the data. Could you provide some detail on how this would be useful?

Comment: We are implementing a 'sync' tool where we would like to sync all new/modified objects in Eloqua with another system. At the moment this tool walks through all data, sorted by a unique field, in a 'history' database and all Eloqua objects to prepare a diff of changes.
Since its a legacy tool we cannot make use of the 'Last modified' filter to get only new/modified objects (which ideally would be the right thing to do).
Basically we rely on sorted data from both sources and just walk through the data comparing corresponding objects.